# How to get date text input in custom HTML dialogue box to load with a value from Google Sheets?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to change the value of a text input on a custom (HTML) dialogue box in Google Sheets to equal a value on my Google Sheet. How can I achieve this?

I'm aware of the correct format of the date that needs to be applied in order to set the .value of the text input. I can use the 'Utilities' service in the .gas.

I've tried using the `onload="getDate()"` event to run a function that sets the value using `var date = new Date()` in `getDate()` and not get the values from the sheet directly but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <style>
    label {font-family: verdana;}

    body {
    border: 1px solid powderblue;
    padding: 30px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body  onload="getDate()">

<form id="myForm">
  <label>Task Number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="taskNumber" value="">
  <br><br>
   <label>Task Date:</label><br>
  <input type="date" name="taskDate" value="" id="demo" >
  <br><br>
   <label>Customer Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="customerName" value="">
  <br><br>
   <label>Customer Site:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="customerSite" value="">
  <br><br>
   <label>Status:</label><br>
  <select name="status">
  <option value="NOSTATUS">Choose</option>
  <option value="ON HOLD">ON HOLD</option>
  <option value="SCHEDULED">SCHEDULED</option>
  <option value="RESCHEDULE">RESCHEDULE</option>
  <option value="WORK IN PROGRESS">WORK IN PROGRESS</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
   <label>Status Date:</label><br>
  <input type="date" name="statusDate" value="">
  <br><br>
   <label>Location:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="location" value="">
  <br><br>
   <label>Description:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="description" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" style="font-family: verdana;" value="Submit" onclick="uploadTask()">

</form> 

  <script>
  function success(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }

  function uploadTask(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
    var obj ={};
    for(var i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++){
        var item = form.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(success)
    .uploadTask(obj);

    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function getDate(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CtH3uNeSiJcRd_ZKE3iWp7TEtAO_B7uCNatGJ7rHMeg');
  var monthly = ss.getSheetByName('MONTHLY');         
  var date = monthly.getRange(1, 1).getValue(); //The value of A:1 = 10/12/2000 date 

  date = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd")

  document.getElementById("demo").value = date;

  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your script, it seems that you want to use GAS in HTML. Is my understanding correct? And if you use GAS, ``SpreadsheetApp.getSheetById()`` occurs an error. In order to understand correctly what you want, can you provide whole script? Of course, please remove your personal information from it. And if you think that it is required to add more information, also please add them to your question.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the feedback, I've added the coded that I want to use. In short I want to set the value of a date to a value from the spreadsheet and I want that value to be updated every time the html dialog box is called because the value of the date in the spreadsheet is always changing. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. From your comment and script, I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not what you want, please tell me. At that time, can you explain the detail about the issue? I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, there is GAS script in HTML. GAS cannot be directly run in HTML.

  - In this case, I used `google.script.run`.
  - The GAS script in `getDate()` was moved from ".html" to ".gs".

#### Modified script:

Please modify `getDate()` in ".html" file to the following script.

```
function getDate() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => {
    document.getElementById("demo").value = e;
  }).getDate();
}
```

Next, please add the following function to ".gs" file.

```
function getDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CtH3uNeSiJcRd_ZKE3iWp7TEtAO_B7uCNatGJ7rHMeg');
  var monthly = ss.getSheetByName('MONTHLY');
  var date = monthly.getRange(1, 1).getValue(); //The value of A:1 = 10/12/2000 date
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
}
```

#### Note:

- ".gs" file is one of scripts in a project you use. I think that it is used to open the dialog.
- If the same function names are in ".gs" file, please modify it.

#### References:

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @Brandon Pillay I could understand correctly about your issue by your update. Thank you, too.