# return value from function in gs to html

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to retrieve string from gs function to sidebar html in google app script

This is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p class="level" dir="rtl">שלב ראשון</p>
        <p class="level" dir="rtl">sic:
            <input type="text" id="sic" value="sic" /p>
                <p class="level" dir="rtl">symbol:
                    <input type="text" id="symbol" value="symbol" /p>
                        <button class="level" onclick="first_step()" dir="rtl">שלב הבא</button>
                <script>
                    function first_step()
                    {var get_sic = document.getElementById("symbol").value;
                    var cik = google.script.run.Xbrl_Gcik(get_sic);
                    documemt.getElementById("cik").value = cik;
                    alert(get_sic);}
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the gs file

```
function Xbrl_Gcik(symbol){
var url = "https://csuite.xbrl.us/php/dispatch.php?                
Task=xbrlCIKLookup&Ticker="+symbol;
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var xml = XmlService.parse(text);
var xml_1 = xml.getRootElement();
var xml_2 = xml_1.getChild('tickerLookup');
var xml_3 = xml_2.getChild('cik').getText();
return xml_3;}
```

Everything works I succeed until the stage of the return in the gs functio

I need help as one who does not even know how I got to this point

Comment: Although I thought that you had posted an answer, was your issue resolved? If your issue is not resolved yet, can I ask you about your current situation?

Comment: Wrap your gs code in a try catch block try { } catch(err) { Logger.log(err); } and see if any error is written to the log file.

Comment: Tanaike - I still could not figure out how to do it

TheWizEd - I did not understand what you meant

Comment: About ``documemt.getElementById("cik").value = cik``. 1. please modify ``documemt`` to ``document``. 2. The tag with ID of ``cik`` cannot be found in your script. 3. I think that this thread is useful for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52976309/7108653

Comment: thank you for the answer
I just fix it five minutes ago I used this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sRuJ6Aee0c